# Extract email addresses from a block of text

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I create an array of email addresses contained within a block of text?
I've tried

`addrs = text.scan(/ .+?@.+? /).map{|e| e[1...-1]}`

but (not surprisingly) it doesn't work reliably.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000214.html

Comment: @Mehrdad:
Disagreed.  Regular expressions server one purpose, but server it very well if used properly.  Detecting email addresses works just fine.
Just comment it well.

Comment: cmartin: I didn't say a thing! I just linked to a related post from Jeff :)

Comment: True...
gotta say that email match is the ugliest I've ever seen... and probably entirely unmaintainable... Sometimes a regex being good as well as readable is more important than that regex being "perfect"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Howabout this for a (slightly) better regular expression

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

You can find this here:

[Email Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Just an FYI, the problem with your email is that you allow only one type of separator before or after an email address.  You would match "@" alone, if separated by spaces.

Comment: There are some TLDs longer than 4 characters, such as ".museum".

Comment: From the article:
"The most frequently quoted example are addresses on the .museum top level domain, which is longer than the 4 letters my regex allows for the top level domain. I accept this trade-off because the number of people using .museum email addresses is extremely low"
It reduces false-pos.

Comment: Finishing the above explained quote:
"To include .museum, you could use ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$. However, then there's another trade-off. This regex will match john@mail.office. It's far more likely that John forgot to type in the .com top level domain"

Comment: Thanks. I get a syntax error with that. I'm not an experienced programmer, and this regex stuff makes my head hurt.

Here's the line with the error:
text.scan(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b).map{|e| e[1...-1]}
text.scan(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b).map{|e| e[1...-1]}

Comment: @cmartin: fair enough, +1. :)

Comment: @Peter:

text.upcase.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/)
...should work fine.  I don't know what you're trying to do with the map part.  You'll get a list of all the email addresses, doing that.  Note the upcase... the regex only matches uppercase (see article)

Comment: Thanks cmartin, that's very helpful. (I also see now that the map part was pointless :-)