# Email regular expression not matching

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code and I want it to check whether or not an email address is in an acceptable format but for some reason the real email addresses I feed it still reply that the email address is invalid. The email address is in string format so unsure as to why I am getting matches.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(u1.EmailAddress, @"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("email is invalid");
}
```

Comment: to modify your regex \b[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,}\b https://regex101.com/r/gK9sS6/1

Might want to check out: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194407/extract-all-email-addresses-from-some-txt-documents-using-ruby

Comment: I would not try to do this myself. Look it up on the net, here's an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I would take this approach, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365407/c-sharp-code-to-validate-email-address/16403290#16403290

Answer (score 3):

You regex only matches to address written in UPPERCASE letter, digits and some symbols.

Use this instead :

```
Regex.IsMatch(u1.EmailAddress, @"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: From regex101.com library, "Match Email" : `/^(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])|([-]|[_]|[.]))+[@](([a-zA-Z0-9])|([-])){2,63}[.](([a-zA-Z0-9]){2,63})+$/gi`

Comment: The `/__PATTERN__/__MODIFIERS__` doesn't work in c#. Modifiers are replaced by `RegexOptions`. Idk, but `/[a-zA-Z]/i` and `[-]|[_]|[.]` seems redundant.